# How can we add a sms subscriber to a data extension from a URL?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a single CTA button that would sign the subscriber up for SMS communications. The subscriber would be added to the data extension that we use for our sms sends from them clicking on the button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you're just trying to insert data into a Data Extension after a user clicks a CTA in an email or web page: You could create a Landing Page with the appropriate AMPScript to pull the data out of the Query String and insert it into the Data Extension using UpsertDE.

Comment: I would have asked for clarification in a comment but my reputation is under 50 so I answered in a couple of ways.

Comment: Think we will go the LP route. Wasn't sure if there was a simpler way to concat a url with a lookup and insert in one

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like you would need an automation process to import the SMS subscribers from that Data Extension into Mobile Connect, if your SMS communications are being sent from Mobile Connect. 
Specific SMS subscriptions must be triggered by the 'Mobile Device' itself, thus the subscriber will not receive any texts until he is subscribed to that Mobile Connect campaign. 
This can be done through a REST API call to QueueMO for whatever Keyword is associated with that campaign. The mobile device being signed up may need to verify, though, if the campaign is a Double Opt In (certain regulations require this).